# Get the containerID, docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've build a container using

```
$docker-compose build
```

How do I get the container's ID ? I tried this, but just gave me the name and not container's ID :

```
$docker-compose ps
```

Comment: Try using `docker ps` (instead of docker-compose) since that will lists the container IDs as well as names. You might need to add `-a` to show all containers.

Comment: docker ps didn't show the container that I was searching for(yes, I'm having multiple containers) but running with -a seemed to be a solution !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **build an image**, and you **run a container** from an image.

Here I believe you are mixing both concepts: the output of your `build` command is an *image* (which you can see using `docker images`), `docker ps` will show you the running *containers*.